# zooming into an svg viewbox of specific dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have this svg, but I can't zoom in and zoom out using this.  I found svg-pan-zoom.js file and tried in it.  Still not working.

```html
<svg id="no.1" viewBox="0 0 2500 2500" transform="translate(100 100)">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2500 2500" id="raptor" style="position:absolute; top: 40px; left: 40px;">
    <rect id="rapt" x="50" y="60" rx="20" ry="20" width="90" height="140" style="fill:#FFB3B3;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;">
    </rect>
    </rect>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Your `<svg>` is not valid, there are two `</rect>`s one after another. Correct this and try again.

Comment: sorry about that. Ive corrected it in my code.but this just doesnt zoom?

Comment: Please adjust your question accordingly and provide a [mcve] to show what you have tried so far and what your actual problem is.